# Fetching repository file list using GitLab Api

Tags: java, rest, gitlab-api

In GitLab I have a project / Repository structure as below.

[image]

**How do i fetch file list from the branches**. As of now I can able to fetch file list from master with the help of the below api.
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example from [the docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/repository_files.html#get-file-from-repository) for the operation "Get file from repository" supports query parameters to specify the ref (a commit, branch, or tag):

```sh
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <your_access_token>" "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/13083/repository/files/app%2Fmodels%2Fkey%2Erb?ref=master"
```

Everything before the `?` is the path to the file, and `ref=master` is specifying the `master` branch, but this can be a commit sha, another branch name, or a tag.

Comment: Yeah it's available in gitlab api documentation itself. It's working as per my expectation. Many Thanks.